# bind causing errors

Tags: jquery

I'm noticing some errors that are occurring because of JQuery bind. What happens is that when I submit a form, bind causes a javascript error to occur when the page that uses it is not loaded. When I comment the bind section out, the error goes away.

Here are the relevant lines of code.

```
  $('input').bind('click', function() {
    editor.post();
  });

  $("#submit").click(function () {
  ...
```

Is there a way to move the bind click function inside of the submit click function? If not, how can I stop this error from occurring?

---

This is the error:

```
editor is not defined
script.js
editor.post();
```

Comment: where do you define editor ? let us see more code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

" bind causes a javascript error
to occur when the page that uses it
is not loaded."

If this is the case then move your code inside document.ready(), then no code will execute untill the document is loaded.

however if u need immediate click handler action with all input element then either use more specific selector to bind so that u can check existence of the code before runnning
or use try-catch :-)

Comment: Seoul. I'm really Javascript stupid. :)  Can you please be more specific? I have an id on the form tag already. Can I use that?

Comment: @jim: ofcourse you can and that will be better :-) hey, not knowing something is not stupidity, dont think like that.

Comment: Thanks Seoul. If you can believe it, I'm actually understanding more about javascript these days. One can only imagine what I was like when I claimed to know nothing at all. :)  I was able to fix this error by just removing the bind click function all together and just moving `editor.post()` into the other click function. Not sure if this is right though.